# Objective-C - Animate button with blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, objective-c-blocks

I have a UIScrollView and a UIButton. I am using blocks to animate them however the button won't animate while the UIScrollView does? Can you not animate a button like this?

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, 768, 200);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 200)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(680, 100, 55, 55);

}



- (IBAction)openMenu:(id)sender {

    if (draw1 == 0) {

        draw1 = 1;
        CGRect optionsDrawer = scrollView.frame;
        CGRect optionsButton = openMenu.frame;
        optionsDrawer.origin.y += 200;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = optionsDrawer;
                             openMenu.frame = optionsButton;
                         }];
    } else {

        draw1 = 0;

        CGRect optionsDrawer = scrollView.frame;
        CGRect optionsButton = openMenu.frame;
        optionsDrawer.origin.y -= 200;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = optionsDrawer;
                             openMenu.frame = optionsButton;
                         }];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I forgot to add the origin to the button as well! Oops!

Fixed with adding to each:

```
optionsButton.origin.y += 200;
```